# What is SQLite? Can put audio file and use with android?

Tags: android, sqlite, avaudioplayer

What is SQLite? Can I put audio file in it and use it with Android?

I want to use it in my project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, SQLite is a relational database available on Android.  It behaves like any other relational database (MySQL, postgres, etc).  But it does have a few differences, such as there are [only 4 data types](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q2).

It could hold audio files (as a BLOB), but it would be better to store the audio file in the filesystem and store the path in the DB.  Of course there might be other ways.  Android provides some helper classes to work with SQLite.

With out knowing what you want to do, here are a few helpful links:

- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org)
- [Data storage on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Hop those help.

Comment: Thank you for every answers.

Mike_D Your understanding is correct.

How do you store the audio file in android project.

Because I want to user install the application can listen to audio files without having to download audio file.

Comment: @YoAkarapolImphrom That part I'm not sure, I have never had to do that.  There might be a way to include as a resource in the project, but this particular case would be more appropriate as seperate question..

Answer (score 0):

Put a string reference to the audio file in SQLite, and then use that string reference to refer to the audio file in your raw folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here to get a better understanding of data storage in Android. SQLite is part of this framework, but is not the only mechanism to persist data in Android.

[Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)